# Can someone help me simplify this JQuery code?

Tags: jquery, simplify

I'm a beginner in jquery with very basic JavaScript knowledge. I tried to search for a tutorial to simplify my codes, but I couldn't find any. Here is my code:

```
$(".trigger_slide1").hover(function () {
    $('.index-img-slide1').toggleClass("show");
});

$(".trigger_slide2").hover(function () {
    $('.index-img-slide2').toggleClass("show");
});

$(".trigger_slide3").hover(function () {
    $('.index-img-slide3').toggleClass("show");
});

$(".trigger_slide4").hover(function () {
    $('.index-img-slide4').toggleClass("show");
});

$(".trigger_slide5").hover(function () {
    $('.index-img-slide5').toggleClass("show");
});
```

And here is my HTML snippet:

```
<div class="index-img">
  <div class="index-img-slide1"><span></span><img src="images/slide1.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="index-img-slide2"><span></span><img src="images/slide2.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="index-img-slide3"><span></span><img src="images/slide3.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="index-img-slide4"><span></span><img src="images/slide4.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="index-img-slide5"><span></span><img src="images/slide5.jpg" alt=""></div>
</div>

<div class="index-canvas">
  <div class="index-navigation-wrapper">
    <div class="container index-navigation-container dropup">
      <ul>
        <li class="trigger_slide1"><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li class="trigger_slide2"><a href="">About</a></li>
        <li class="trigger_slide3"><a href="">Portfolios</a></li>
        <li class="trigger_slide4"><a href="">Quotes</a></li>
        <li class="trigger_slide5"><a href="">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gef91owt/

This pretty much pictures what am I trying to do right now. Is there a way to simplify this?

Comment: what do you mean by simplify exactly ? Do you want to make it short or something else ?

Comment: Yes. As you can see, I will have to update my codes manually if I want to add another ".index-img-slide". :)

Comment: It is better if you can post sample of html snippet.

Comment: Consider using a single class for all your elements so that you can apply the hover handler to all of them in one call.

Comment: Hi @cafonso thanks for your tips but my jquery knowledge is very limited.

Comment: @sandalkoyak Sure. I'll try to write a more detailed answer for you later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change js (according to your fiddle) to

```
$('[class^="trigger_div"]').hover(function() {
    var i = $(this).index();
    $('.triggered-divs').children().eq(i).toggleClass('show');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rrehan/gef91owt/1/

Answer (score 1):

It is better if you change your **html** and **class** structure using a generic class like this:

```
<ul>        
    <li class="trigger_slide1 trigger_slide"><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li class="trigger_slide2 trigger_slide"><a href="">About</a></li>
    <li class="trigger_slide3 trigger_slide"><a href="">Portfolios</a></li>
    <li class="trigger_slide4 trigger_slide"><a href="">Quotes</a></li>
    <li class="trigger_slide5 trigger_slide"><a href="">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

And then:

```
$(".trigger_slide").hover(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("show");     
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dq3aLd4t/

Comment: Thank you sir. But it's not working. Should I simply copy the script or did I missed anything? Thank you for your help.

Comment: 1 sec, I'm trying it on jsfiddle

Comment: @sandalkoyak This is pretty much what I was talking about in my previous comment.

Comment: @cafonso I know this method but actually I would like to toggle class "show" into "index-img-slide" not "trigger_slide". :)

Comment: Added a working jsfiddle using the same script. All i need is to simplify the script instead of mark it using trigger_div1 for div1_triggered and trigger_div2 for div2_triggered.